# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property

Tags: javascript

I was trying out this really simple example from the awesome "Professional JavaScript for Web Developers" book by Nicholas Zakas but I can't figure what I am doing wrong here. Must be something really simple that I missed but I'm stuck.

Here is the code:

```
'use strict';

var book = {};

Object.defineProperties(book, {
    originYear: {
        value: 2004,
        writable: false
    },

    _year: {
        value: 2004
    },

    edition: {
        value: 1
    },

    year : {
        get: function() {
            return this._year;
        },

        set: function(newValue) {
            if(newValue > this.originYear) {
                this._year = newValue;
                this.edition += newValue - this.originYear;
            }
        }
    }
});

console.log(book.edition);
book.year = 2006;
console.log(book.edition);
```

The error I am getting on the Chrome console is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '_year' of
> #main.js:31 Object.defineProperties.year.setmain.js:39 (anonymous function)

Can someone please explain where I have gone wrong?

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/csssolver296/gvgf6r1a/)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

When you use `Object.defineProperties`, by default `writable` is set to `false`, so `_year` and `edition` are actually **read only** properties.

Explicitly set them to `writable: true`:

```
_year: {
    value: 2004,
    writable: true
},

edition: {
    value: 1,
    writable: true
},
```

Check out [**MDN for this method**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties).

> **`writable`**
>   `true` if and only if the value associated with the property may be changed with an assignment operator.
>   Defaults to `false`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer as it lead me to my solution. I had a variable: `var thisObject = {name: 'a name', id: 1};` and at some point in the code I was setting `thisObject = 1;` (i think it was old code or just didn't write it properly...and when I tried to use or set `thisObject.name` after that I received this error message. Removing the line where I set `thisObject` to an integer fixed my issue.  Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with a Nextjs React setup. If I fired a state setting function it would happen on re-render (firing an onClick function), but not if I loaded the page directly or via refresh.
Making a copy of the non editable, or in my case "frozen" object before modifying parameters fixed the problem for me.
I was passing an object in Via json and then trying to set some additional properties of it.

```
book = {...book} 
book.year = 2006;
```

My own setup looked more like this,

```
let linkStyle={}
if (appearance.LinkStyle) {
 linkStyle = apperance.LinkStyle
}

linkStyle.color = appearance.primaryColor // Same Error here
```

Resolved by

```
let linkStyle={}
if (appearance.LinkStyle) {
  linkStyle = {...apperance.LinkStyle}
}

linkStyle.color = appearance.primaryColor
```

Answer (score 0):

If sometimes [a link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties)! will not work.
so create a temporary object and take all values from the writable object then change the value and assign it to the writable object. it should perfectly.

```
var globalObject = {
    name:"a",
    age:20
}
function() {
    let localObject = {
    name:'a',
    age:21
    }
    this.globalObject = localObject;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried changing `year` to a different term, and it worked.

```
public_methods : {
    get: function() {
        return this._year;
    },

    set: function(newValue) {
        if(newValue > this.originYear) {
            this._year = newValue;
            this.edition += newValue - this.originYear;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this. But it still throws an error on encountering that assignment to the _year property. Did it execute the assignment without throwing an error for you? Thanks

Comment: Leo's answer is correct. Marked down because the answer suggests changing a variable name randomly to fix the bug which would be fixing errors carelessly and probably creating more bugs.