# Update value of object in array with values in other Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to reproduce my original problem;
I have two arrays in react state Array 1 is an original array from Database and Array2 is an updated array is  state.

Objective is to update  only changed rates and not quantity (and other pararmters) back to the Database, hence i need to update the values of **rates in object of Array1** with the values of the **rates in object 2** for a the objects of Array1 matching with the objects in Array2.

```
Array1 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: IceCream,
    details: [{ id: "12", name: "milk", quantity: "50", rate: "100" },
    { id: "13", name: "cream", quantity: "50", rate: "300" }]
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: Coffee,
    details: [{ id: "14", name: "Coffee bean", quantity: "60", rate: "200" },
    { id: "15", name: "water", quantity: "60", rate: "300" }]

},
{
    id: 3,
    name: Tea,
    details: [{ id: "16", name: "Tea leaf", quantity: "50", rate: "700" }]
}]


Array2 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: IceCream,
    details: [{ id: "12", name: "milk", quantity: "50", rate: "500" },
    { id: "13", name: "cream", quantity: "50", rate: "700" }]
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: Coffee,
    details: [{ id: "14", name: "Coffee bean", quantity: "60", rate: "800" },
    { id: "15", name: "water", quantity: "60", rate: "8000" }]
}]
```

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice?

Comment: My Apologies Sir..I was not able to reproduce problem correctly in my previous attempt..

Comment: Fastest way would be to have extra hashmaps of each column's value as key and value as id for faster search (more like caching). Otherwise you will have toloop through smaller array, and then loop through bigger array and find the matches manually using if conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over the objects in `Array1` using `.map`, check if it exists in `Array2` by `id` using `.find`. Then, iterate over the details and update the rate if it also exists in that of the second array:

```js
let Array1 = [
{
     id:1,
     name: "IceCream",
     details:[
          {id:"12",name:"milk",quantity:"50",rate:"100"}, 
          {id:"13",name:"cream",quantity:"50",rate:"300"}
     ]
},
{
     id:2,
     name:"Coffee",
     details:[
          {id:"14",name:"Coffee bean",quantity:"60",rate:"200"},
          {id:"15",name:"water",quantity:"60",rate:"300"}
     ]
},
{ 
     id:3,
     name:"Tea",
     details:[
          {id:"16",name:"Tea leaf",quantity:"50",rate:"700"}
     ]
}
]

let Array2 = [
{
     id:1,
     name: "IceCream",
     details:[
          {id:"12",name:"milk",quantity:"50",rate:"500"}, 
          {id:"13",name:"cream",quantity:"50",rate:"700"}
     ]
},
{
     id:2,
     name:"Coffee",
     details:[
          {id:"14",name:"Coffee bean",quantity:"60",rate:"800"},
          {id:"15",name:"water",quantity:"60",rate:"8000"}
     ]     
}
]

Array1 = Array1.map(item => {
     let element = Array2.find(e => e.id == item.id);
     if(element){
          item.details = item.details.map(e => {
               let detail = element.details.find(d => d.id==e.id);
               if(detail)
                    e.rate = detail.rate;
               return e;
          });
     }
     return item;
});

console.log(Array1);
```

Comment: HI Majed Thank you for you time.When I put this code in my application I am getting " Cannot assign to read only property 'rate' of object '#<Object>'"

Comment: let r = [...state.basicRecipe];

    let Array2 = [...state.recipeBasicRecipes];

    r = r.map(item => {
      let element = Array2.find(e => e._id == item._id);
      if (element) {
        item.details = item.details.map(e => {
          let detail = element.details.find(d => d._id == e._id);
          if (detail) e.rate = detail.rate;
          return e;
        });
      }
      return item;
    });

    console.log(r);

Comment: How are the elements added in the first place? Check out these: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Read-only https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27519836/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-assign-to-read-only-property

Comment: These arrays are part of the react state.

Comment: Oh, I cannot help a lot here. But I think there should be a special method to update the state. Research more about the problem using React.