# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property while updating state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to reproduce my original problem.

I have two arrays in react state, and `Array1` is the original array from Database and `Array2` is the updated array in  state.

The objective is to update only changed `rate` and not `quantity` (and other properties) back to the Database, hence i need to update the values of **rates in object of `basicrecipe`** with the values of the **rates in object of `recipeBasicRecipe` array** for a the objects of  `basicrecipe` matching with the objects in `recipeBasicRecipe`.

I am getting this error when I run the code, request help

> `Error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property`

```js
let basicRecipes = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: IceCream,
    details: [{ id: "12", name: "milk", quantity: "50", rate: "100" },
    { id: "13", name: "cream", quantity: "50", rate: "300" }]
  },
  {
      id: 2,
      name: Coffee,
      details: [{ id: "14", name: "Coffee bean", quantity: "60", rate: "200" },
      { id: "15", name: "water", quantity: "60", rate: "300" }]

  },
  {
      id: 3,
      name: Tea,
      details: [{ id: "16", name: "Tea leaf", quantity: "50", rate: "700"      
      }]
}]


let recipeBasicRecipe = [
  {
      id: 1,
      name: IceCream,
      details: [{ id: "12", name: "milk", quantity: "50", rate: "500" },
      { id: "13", name: "cream", quantity: "50", rate: "700" }]
  },
  {
      id: 2,
      name: Coffee,
      details: [{ id: "14", name: "Coffee bean", quantity: "60", rate: "800" },
      { id: "15", name: "water", quantity: "60", rate: "8000" }]
  }
];

let r = basicRecipe;

let Array2 = recipeBasicRecipes;

r = r.map(item => {
  let element = Array2.find(e => e.id == item.id);
  if (element) {
    item.details = item.details.map(e => {
      let detail = element.details.find(d => d.id == e.id);
      if (detail) {
        e.rate = detail.rate;
      }
      return e;
    });
  }
  return item;
});

console.log(r);
```

Posing the relevant react ccode:

```
const initialState = {

    basicRecipe: [],

    recipeBasicRecipes: [],
   
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(recipeManagementReducer, initialState);
```

Function where I am executing this code

```
  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    /**
    * 
    setShowLoader();
    updateawMateris(state.recipeRawMaterials);
    *  */

    let r = state.basicRecipe;

    let Array2 = state.recipeBasicRecipes;

    r = r.map(item => {
      let element = Array2.find(e => e._id == item._id);
      if (element) {
        item.details = item.details.map(e => {
          let detail = element.details.find(d => d._id == e._id);
          if (detail) {
            e.rate = detail.rate;
          }
          return e;
        });
      }
      return item;
    });
```

While playing around I changed the return to make it immutable as that was cause of the errors.

Here is the snippet, only problem is this returns change on Quantity in recipe as well, how do I avoid that

```
    let r = [...state.basicRecipe];

    let Array2 = [...state.recipeBasicRecipes];

    r = r.map(item => {
      let element = Array2.find(e => e._id === item._id);
      if (element) {
        item.details = item.details.map(e => {
          let detail = element.details.find(d => d._id === e._id);
          if (detail) {
            return {
              ...e,
              rate: detail.rate
            };
          }
          return e;
        });
      }
      return item;
    });

    console.log(r);
```

Comment: This will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27519836/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-assign-to-read-only-property ... you can further explore here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties

Comment: Not able to understand where exactly do I make these changes..Can you pls help

Comment: I'll have to apologize for the delay, I was a bit busy. I have provided another lead below, please check and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after doing some research on this for you I came to realize that some of the properties in your returned data are non-writable.

For example the error:

> Cannot assign to read only property 'rate' of object '#'

Happens because `rate` or item `e` in your `map` is not mutable. For it to work, you will have to create copy of that data indread of storing it's reference on your variables here:

```
let r = state.basicRecipe;

let Array2 = state.recipeBasicRecipes;
```

`r` and `Array2` are just references to your state properties.

---

You may want to instead make new copies of that data. Like this:

```
let r = [...state.basicRecipe];

let Array2 = [...state.recipeBasicRecipes];
```

and then run your code and modify properties that you want to change.

---

Here is a minimal reproduction of your scenario and I don't get any errors. Please check this and advise?

```js
class Something extends React.Component{

  state = {
     basicRecipes : [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "IceCream",
        details: [{ id: "12", name: "milk", quantity: "50", rate: "100" },
        { id: "13", name: "cream", quantity: "50", rate: "300" }]
      },
      {
          id: 2,
          name: "Coffee",
          details: [{ id: "14", name: "Coffee bean", quantity: "60", rate: "200" },
          { id: "15", name: "water", quantity: "60", rate: "300" }]

      },
      {
          id: 3,
          name: "Tea",
          details: [{ id: "16", name: "Tea leaf", quantity: "50", rate: "700"      
          }]
    }],
    recipeBasicRecipe : [
      {
          id: 1,
          name: "IceCream",
          details: [{ id: "12", name: "milk", quantity: "50", rate: "500" },
          { id: "13", name: "cream", quantity: "50", rate: "700" }]
      },
      {
          id: 2,
          name: "Coffee",
          details: [{ id: "14", name: "Coffee bean", quantity: "60", rate: "800" },
          { id: "15", name: "water", quantity: "60", rate: "8000" }]
      }
    ]
  };

  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.performSomeAction = this.performSomeAction.bind(this);
  }
  
  performSomeAction()
  {
    let r = [...this.state.basicRecipes];
    let Array2 = [...this.state.recipeBasicRecipe];

    return r.map(item => {
      let element = Array2.find(e => e.id === item.id);
      let tempItem = {...item}; // Make a mutable copy of Item
      if (element) {
        tempItem.details = item.details.map(e => {
          let detail = element.details.find(d => d.id === e.id);
          let tempE = {...e}; // Make a mutable copy of e
          
          if (detail) {
            tempE.rate = detail.rate;
          }
          return tempE;
        });
      }
      return tempItem;
    });
  }
  
  render()
  {
    console.log(this.performSomeAction());
    
    return(
      <h1>Code Runs</h1>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Something />, 
document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Still it persists..I think i has got to do with the immutability,, Can you help me correctly spread this updated value. I am trying at my end as well

Comment: Alright, Please check the answer again. Unfortunately, I can only work with what you provided and as far as i've tried, the code runs. Otherwise, you'll need to provide a repro that throws those errors and then I can assist.

Comment: Yup make some sort of gist on GitHub or show more logs and code please

Comment: I added the snippet with the spread operator in the code, it works but it changes the quantity as well..Can pls advise how to resolve the same

Comment: https://github.com/SagarMahadik/singularitynew/tree/master/client/src/components/Singularity/OwnerView/CafeManagement/RecipeManagement/state

Comment: Here is the repo. relevant code is in onSubmit function

Comment: Well the mistake is because you spread `item` and not `e`. You must spread `e` like this `return { ...e, rate: detail.rate}` not `item`.

Comment: Check how I've done it on my snippet above.

Comment: I am sorry..I am trying this but getting RecipeManagementState.js:394 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'details' of object

Comment: I edited my snippet for your reference.

Comment: I have solved that also.. You can do exactly what you did with `e` for item

Comment: The idea is to spread `item` and only change `details` property.

Comment: Finally..You resolved it..thanks a lot for all the pain you have taken..

Comment: Awesome! I am glad you can now continue with the project. I am also glad I could help, and you've been very cooperative. Please, check the snipped again.. I've used a mutable copy approach and I think this is the best option. But it's the same thing really.