# Cannot override value of property in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm working in my angular project, but I'm having issues as the properties of one of my model class appears as read only, so I cannot mofify its value.

My class is the following:

```
export class Pageable {
    page!: number;
    quantity!: number;
    search!: string | undefined;
    order!: string;
    key!: string;

    constructor(key: string) {
        this.page = 1;
        this.quantity = 20;
        this.order = 'ASC';
        this.key = key;
    }
}
```

In my component I instanciate the model as follows

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
     pageable = new Pageable('name');
```

Then, when I need to modify the value of any of its properties like the following:

```
onKeyUp(event: any){
    this.pageable.search = event.target.value;
    this.findList(this.pageable);
}

findList(request: Pageable){
    this.categoryStore.dispatch(findListAction({query: request}));
  }
```

I get `ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'search' of object '[object Object]'`

This is the effect

```
find$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(findListAction),
      exhaustMap((action) =>
        this.categoryService.findList(action.query).pipe(
          map((res: FindResponseModel) => listSuccessAction({ res }))
      )
    )
  );
```

And this is the reducer:

```
on(listSuccessAction, (state, {res}) => ({list: res, item: null})),
```

And the state is

```
export interface CategoryState{
    list: FindResponseModel | null;
    item: CategoryModel | null;
}
```

And this is the method in the component

```
this.categoryStore.pipe(select(listSelector)).subscribe((response: FindResponseModel | null) => {
      this.categories = [];
      if (!response) return;
      response.items.forEach((item: CategoryModel) => {
        this.categories.push(item);
      });
      this.pageable = {...response.request};
    });
```

Comment: Are you using NGRX?

Comment: Can you share what is inside `findList` ?

Comment: Is onKeyUp() in the same component?

Comment: @jburtondev yes, I'm using NGRX.

Comment: @robert I updated the question with the findList function

Comment: @CharlieV onKeyUp is for an autocomplete that fires that findlist with the search property updated.

Comment: can you share the reducer and the `findListAction` too

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27519836/5468463 ?

Comment: @Vega I'm not using Object.defineProperties.. That's why I don't understand why they are read only

Comment: @robert I added more information about NGRX

Comment: The reason you're getting that issue is because the store in NGRX is immutable. Try using a spread operator to create a brand new copy of the array or using a reducer to modify the data.

Comment: !: string | undefined; => !: and | undefined are contradictory. Might be irritated, but still needs to be corrected

Comment: And I know the error should come from here:       this.pageable = {...response.request};

Comment: @Vega how can I replace the {...response.request} ?

Comment: Why  search has !: and undefined type at the time here?   search!: string | undefined;