# Cannot assign to read only property 'url' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I tried changing a key's value inside my object, but it seems like I have been mutating the state.

The issue happens in state dispatch

**Code:**

```
export function nameList(id, rank, sub) {
  const { nameItem: name } = store.getState().nameListSlice; //gets the nameItem state

  if (!name.length || name.length === 0) {
         const newName = [
  {
    name: "Male",
    url: getNameUrl("Male", id, rank, sub),
    icon: "Male",
    toolTip: "Male",
    active: false,
    idName: "male",
  },

  {
    name: "Female",
    url: getNameUrl("Female", id, rank, sub),
    icon: "Female",
    toolTip: "Female",
    active: false,
    idName: "female",
  },
];

store.dispatch(updateDetails(newName)); //The issue happen here
  } else {
    return name.map((n) => {
      n.url = getNameUrl(n.name, id, rank, sub);
      return n;
    });
  }
}

// This function returns a url
function getNameUrl(type, id, rank, sub) {
  switch (type) {
    case "Male": {
      return `/male/${id}/${rank}/${sub}`;
    }
    case "Female": {
      return `/female/${id}/${rank}/${sub}`;
    }
  }
}
```

**Reducer/Action: (redux toolkit)**

```
export const nameListSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'nameItem',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    updateDetails: (state,action) => {
      state.nameItem = action.payload
    },
  },
})

export const { updateDetails } = nameListSlice.actions

export default nameListSlice.reducer
```

**The error I get:**

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'url' of object '#<Object>'
```

This happens in the above code disptach -  `store.dispatch(updateDetails(newName));`
Commenting this code, fixes the issue.
How to dispatch without this error ?

Also based on this [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27519836/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-assign-to-read-only-property)

But still same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RTK use [immerjs](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/) underly, `nameItem` state slice is not a mutable draft of immerjs when you get it by using `store.getState().nameListSlice`. You can use the immutable update function [createNextState](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/other-exports#createnextstate) to perform [immutable update patterns](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/update-patterns).

Why you can mutate the state in case reducers are created by `createSlice` like `state.nameItem = action.payload;`?

`createSlice` use `createReducer` to create case reducers. See the comments for [createReducer](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/v1.8.5/packages/toolkit/src/createReducer.ts#L88):

```
/**
 * A utility function that allows defining a reducer as a mapping from action
 * type to *case reducer* functions that handle these action types. The
 * reducer's initial state is passed as the first argument.
 *
 * @remarks
 * The body of every case reducer is implicitly wrapped with a call to
 * `produce()` from the [immer](https://github.com/mweststrate/immer) library.
 * This means that rather than returning a new state object, you can also
 * mutate the passed-in state object directly; these mutations will then be
 * automatically and efficiently translated into copies, giving you both
 * convenience and immutability.
```

The body of every case reducer is implicitly wrapped with a call to
`produce()`, that's why you can mutate the state inside case reducer function.

But if you get the state slice outside the case reducer, it's not a mutable draft state, so you can't mutate it directly like `n.url = 'xxx'`.

E.g.

```
import { configureStore, createNextState, createSlice, isDraft } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState: { nameItem: any[] } = { nameItem: [{ url: '' }] };
export const nameListSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'nameItem',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    updateDetails: (state, action) => {
      state.nameItem = action.payload;
    },
  },
});
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    nameListSlice: nameListSlice.reducer,
  },
});

const { nameItem: name } = store.getState().nameListSlice;

console.log('isDraft: ', isDraft(name));

const nextNames = createNextState(name, (draft) => {
  draft.map((n) => {
    n.url = `/male`;
    return n;
  });
});

console.log('nextNames: ', nextNames);
```

Output:

```bash
isDraft:  false
nextNames:  [ { url: '/male' } ]
```